# How to list all available registered clients?

Tags: twilio

Using the twilio javascript client I can register a client like that:

```
capability.AllowClientIncoming("jenny");
```

Now let's say I have a number of people opening their browser and registering: "jenny", "benny", "teddy", "smitty"...

Is there a way I can list all the registered clients? Either with the twilio.js library or the REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

So you can use the [`Twilio.Device.presence()`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device#presence) handler for this. It will be called once for each other client user, so you can create a list from that. If the state of any of the other client agents changes, the handler is called again.

```
Twilio.Device.presence(function (presenceEvent) {
  console.log(presenceEvent.from + " available: " + presenceEvent.available;
});
```

There is a page to describe this feature on the [Twilio Blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/09/twilio-client-presence-for-everyone.html) too. Lots more information on the [Twilio Docs page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device).

Comment: Question, is .presence handler being called for every client, including the one registered with Twilio.Device.setup(my-token); in the page? Because it looks like it does not, or I am doing something wrong.